# Wand python get pixel color with GIF

Tags: python, wand, magickwand

I want get rgb color some pixel in gif

```py
from wand.image import Image
with Image(blob=img, format='JPG') as picture:
    print picture[1][1].string 
    # return srgb(0,0,0) is good
```

Problem:

```py
from wand.image import Image
with Image(blob=img, format='GIF') as picture:
    print picture[1][1].string 
    # return srgb(93%,93%,93%) why?
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how color compliance works. Not all parts of the pixel in question can be represented as a 8-bit unsigned integer, so it's represented as a normalized percent -- between `0%` and `100%`.

Try the following...

```py
from wand.image import Image
with Image(blob=img, format='GIF') as picture:
    picture.depth = 8
    print picture[1, 1].string
    #=> srgb(274,274,274)
```

Comment: still return srgb(26%,27%,26%)

Comment: If that's the case, then you'll need to do `(pixel.red_int8, pixel.green_int8, pixel.blue_int8)`, but you can't stop '%' from showing up. Compliance will never show `srgb(66.3, 68.85000000000001, 66.3)`

Answer (score 1):

This is my code for png (python3)

```
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename='white_background_320x200_edited_alphaoff.png') as img:
    print(img[1][1])
```